# Elasticsearch - Match hex number of fixed number of digits

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have been trying to match using query_string and wildcard to exclude some values in my data.

I have values of the following type among others:

qa4689f54ad-XYXY

So the value starts with a ‘q’, then I have a hex number of 10-digits, followed by a hyphen and then the rest.

I tried the obvious q[a-fA-F0-9]{10}* expression (with the escape \) but it doesn’t match!

When I try the same regular expression on regex tester websites it matches perfectly.

I have gone thru maybe 10 questions related to regex in Elasticsearch but in vain.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: "with the escape \" - What is that supposed to mean? There are no \ in that regex, so there is nothing to escape. Show the expression you're using, precisely and with more context.

Comment: Have to check if the string contains newlines? Try `q[a-fA-F0-9]{10}(.|\n)*`

Answer (score 1):

`{10}*` is not a valid construct in regular expressions.

You mean:

```
q[a-fA-F0-9]{10}.*
```

or (to make sure the hyphen is there):

```
q[a-fA-F0-9]{10}-.*
```

or (to make sure the match occurs at the start of the string)

```
^q[a-fA-F0-9]{10}-.*
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. ^ is not allowed in Elasticsearch, as for the .* instead of *, it didn’t fix it. I will check more.

Comment: @Rakesh Ah, I didn't know. The rest of the expression is supported though, and `.*` is definitely the correct way to say "any character". Please add to your question the entire query JSON you send.